Getting error while connecting to a SQL Server DB using DBI & ODBC package in R on a linux Server
I'm using this R code to connect to a SQL Server DB from a linux server:
library(DBI)

con <- dbConnect(
    odbc::odbc(),
    driver = "Sql Server",
    server = "server",
    database = "db_name",
    uid = "uid",
    pwd = "pwd"
)

And, I'm getting this error :

Error in dbConnect():
! ODBC failed with error 00000 from [FreeTDS][SQL Server].
✖ Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist
• Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist
• Unable to connect to data source
ℹ From nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1150.
Run rlang::last_trace() to see where the error occurred.

I'm using DBI version 1.2.3.
Here's how my odbcinst.ini file looks in /etc :
vi odbcinst.ini

Setup           = /usr/lib/libodbcpsqlS.so
Driver64        = /usr/lib64/psqlodbcw.so
Setup64         = /usr/lib64/libodbcpsqlS.so
FileUsage       = 1


# Driver from the mysql-connector-odbc package
# Setup from the unixODBC package

[MySQL]
Description     = ODBC for MySQL
Driver          = /usr/lib/libmyodbc5.so
Setup           = /usr/lib/libodbcmyS.so
Driver64        = /usr/lib64/libmyodbc5.so
Setup64         = /usr/lib64/libodbcmyS.so
FileUsage       = 1


# Driver from the freetds-libs package
# Setup from the unixODBC package

[FreeTDS]
Description     = Free Sybase & MS SQL Driver
Driver          = /usr/lib/libtdsodbc.so
Setup           = /usr/lib/libtdsS.so
Driver64        = /usr/lib64/libtdsodbc.so
Setup64         = /usr/lib64/libtdsS.so
Port            = 1433


# Driver from the mariadb-connector-odbc package

# Setup from the unixODBC package

[MariaDB]
Description     = ODBC for MariaDB
Driver          = /usr/lib/libmaodbc.so
Driver64        = /usr/lib64/libmaodbc.so
FileUsage       = 1



[Sql Server]
Description     = ODBC for SQLSERVER
Driver64        = /usr/lib64/libtdsodbc.so.0.0.0
Setup64         = /usr/lib64/libtdsS.so.2.0.0
FileUsage       = 1

Any help to resolve this issue would be highly appreciated! Thanks all!

Have you tried using your code to connect to a server hosted on your machine?

No I haven't.. Because I need the code to work on a linux machine

The error looks pretty self-explanatory? You don't seem to be able to access whatever host name  is, or you haven't setup the parameters correctly. What's the real hostname? Is it behind a firewall, or perhaps a named instance? Did you try pinging it or tracing from linux

Is the [Sql Server] section something you added to the odbcinst.ini file yourself? It's quite unusual to be using Driver64 and Setup64 keys, and the library versions don't seem to match.

Using RODBC package I'm able to fetch the data into R from the same DB server. Can't share the DB server IP here.. I'm using DB server IP to make a connection

Have you looked for any freetds.conf files on the system to see if they have any aliases configured for the server you're using in the dbConnect request?

Didn't check any freetds.conf files.. Do you have any recommendation to check any specific files? Yes using dbConnect function from DBI package
